# Ocultar contraseña con asteriscos C++

Tags: c++, dev-c++, c++17

tengo el siguiente módulo para validar una contraseña, pero me piden que en consola al momento de digitar la contraseña esté oculta con asteriscos Ej: si digitas la contraseña holamundo que te muestre en consola mientras la escribes ********. Cual sería la forma más eficiente para hacerlo? Gracias de antemano.

```
void verificarContrasena(char Contrasena[]){

int i,k;
char caracter;
HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE );

cout << "\t================================" << endl;
cout << "\t       VALIDAR CONTRASENA" << endl;
cout << "\t================================" << endl;
cout << "\tIngrese la contrasena a validar: ";
cin>>Contrasena;


bool numero = false;
bool mayuscula = false;
bool simbolo = false;
k = strlen(Contrasena);

if(k>12){
    for(i=0;i<k;i++){
        if(isdigit(Contrasena[i])){
        numero = true;
    }
    if(isalpha(Contrasena[i])){
        mayuscula = true;
    }
    if(Contrasena[i] >= '!' and Contrasena[i] <= '/'){
        simbolo = true;
    }
    }
}

if(numero == true and mayuscula == true and simbolo == true){
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, 2);
    cout << "\tLa contrasena es fuerte!" << endl << endl;
} 
else{
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, 4);
    cout << "\tLa contrasena es debil!" << endl;
}
```

}

Comment: Veo que estas en windows. Lo mas sencillo es leer caracteres con [`getch`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h) hasta que te topes con un `\n`. Por cada carácter que leas escribe un asterisco (Excepto a donde te topes con el salto de linea).

Comment: Perfecto, lo intentaré, muchas gracias !! :)